# Access serial port in web worker

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, serial-port

I want to access the [serial port](https://web.dev/serial/) `navigator.serial.requestPort()` in web worker, but I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: navigator.serial.requestPort is not a function

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call requestPort from a worker, you'll need to call requestPort in the main application code then tell the worker to open the port.

Main code:

```
await navigator.serial.requestPort();

workerRef.current.postMessage('connect');
```

Worker Code:

```
onmessage = async (evt) => {
    if (evt.data === 'connect') {
        [port] = await navigator.serial.getPorts();

        const info = await port.open({ baudRate: 19200 });
    }
}
```

[Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6puf8e-1fpb12)