# Transfer data in serial port when browser minimized

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, rxjs, serial-port

I want to use [web serial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API) in my web app.
one problem I have is when user change or minimized browser the timer for send and receive data stoped.I test web worker and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67590440/access-serial-port-in-web-worker)
how can I fix this
my code is like this and use [rxjs timer](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer)

```
      //user give access to serial port
     const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
 
     await port.open({ baudRate: 9600 });

     const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
     const readableStreamClosed = port.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
     const reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();
     const textEncoder = new TextEncoderStream();
     const writableStreamClosed = textEncoder.readable.pipeTo(port.writable);
     const writer = textEncoder.writable.getWriter();

     timer(40, 100).subscribe(async (c) => {
        await writer.write("{Config:1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}");
        console.log((await reader.read()).value);
     });
```

update I use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) but dont work my code is like this

```
    const textDecoder = new TextDecoderStream();
    const readableStreamClosed = this.port.readable.pipeTo(textDecoder.writable);
    this.reader = textDecoder.readable.getReader();
    const textEncoder = new TextEncoderStream();
    const writableStreamClosed = textEncoder.readable.pipeTo(this.port.writable);
    this.writer = textEncoder.writable.getWriter();

    setInterval( async () => {
      await this.writer.write("{Config:1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}");
      console.log((await this.reader.read().value);
    },100);
```

Comment: What browser we are talking about? What is your "browser"?

Comment: As you discovered, web workers can't directly access the serial interface, and web browsers will drastically reduce resources given to backgrounded tabs. It may even completely kill the tab if the resources are required. This is prevent lots of open tabs from bringing a users computer to a slow crawl. So I don't think what you want here is possible.